# Reading dates with JuliaDB

Tags: julia, juliadb

I am very new to Julia, and I am having an issue with JuliaDB loadtable("myfile").If I understand well, the problem is that the dates are in the format dd/mm/yyyy, e.g. 21/07/1985. I am told 'ArgumentError:Month: 14 out of range (1:12). How can I tell Julia the format of the date of the file I am reading?

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://github.com/JuliaData/JuliaDB.jl/issues/295), you can use the argument `colparsers` to solve your issue:

```
loadtable(path, colparsers=Dict(:datecol => dateformat"MM/DD/YYYY"))
```